# Input inside Select Angular

Tags: angular, select

I have a small piece of code in which I have a `select` i `option`. With their help, I iterate through the elements and select the one I need. The point is that I need to do a search inside this `select`. That is, I can both select an item from the list and start typing, looking for the item I need and the items are shown to me.

```
<mat-select formControlName="targetListValue">
   <input>
   <mat-option [selected]="true" [value]="null"></mat-option>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let targetItem of targetListOptions" [value]="targetItem.id">
      {{ targetItem.name }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Is mat-autosuggest what you’re looking for maybe?

Comment: @MikeOne i don't know what it is but i need to put input inside select to make search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the idea of 'autocomplete' control.

[angular material](https://material.angular.io/) provides an [autoComplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component that contains a select with input:

> The autocomplete is a normal text input enhanced by a panel of suggested options.

HTML CODE:

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS CODE:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Highlight the first autocomplete option
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl('');
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

CSS:

```css
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why do you `mat-autocomplete`? I can't scroll in my `select` to see all my elements. Is that how it should work?

Comment: sorry to ask youm but how to do it??? can you show me it, please??? thanks

Comment: mat-autocomplete will automatically display a vertical scroll bar when there are too many options to display in the panel.

Comment: yes, i have a lot of them but i don't see scrool vertical. How to fix it? Thanks)

Comment: Please open a new question "How to display a vertical scroll bar in mat-autocomplete"